# NSOperation - main method runs on the main thread?

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsoperation

Why does my NSOperation subclass run the main method on the main thread? I want it to run asynchronously.

```
@interface ServiceClient : NSOperation
@end

@implementation ServiceClient

- (void)main
{
   if ([[NSThread currentThread] isEqual:[NSThread mainThread]])
   {
      NSLog(@"Why does this get called on the main thread");
   }
}

@end
```

Starting the operation

```
ServiceClient *serviceClient = [[ServiceClient aloc] init];
[serviceClient start];
```

**EDIT:**

Documentation suggest overriding isCuncurrent and returning yes, but the method does not get called.

```
- (BOOL)isConcurrent
{
   return YES;
}
```

Comment: Do you get the same behavior from starting the operation via a NSOperationQueue?

Comment: Just out of interest, does [NSThread isMainThread] also return true? I'm not sure about your equality test.

Comment: I tried adding the operation to an NSOperationQueue and that runs it in the background (different thread), but is it possible to run the operation on a separate thread without adding it to an OperationQueue?

Comment: @Senior yes [NSThread isMainThread] returned true

Comment: Try something that will lock the UI in your main implementation to verify that it is for sure running on the main thread.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set up your own thread in the `start` method

Snippet taken from [Concurrency Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/OperationObjects/OperationObjects.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008091-CH101-SW1)

> **start**
>   (Required) All concurrent operations must override this method and replace the default behavior with their own custom implementation. To execute an operation manually, you call its start method. Therefore, your implementation of this method is the starting point for your operation and is where you set up the thread or other execution environment in which to execute your task. Your implementation must not call super at any time.

If you add your `NSOperation` to an `NSOperationQueue` it takes care of this for you.